# Activerecord logging sql format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord

I use Sinatra as webserver with activerecord as ORM.
My adapter is oracle_enhanced.
I activate logging like this

```
LOG = Logger.new( "./logs/#{File.basename(__FILE__)}_log.txt", 'daily' )
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = LOG
ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging = false
```

Everything is ok except when I update the model it is logged in this form

```
D, [2018-11-05T09:38:11.426185 #5540] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "MYTABLE" 
SET "DESCRIPTION" = :a1 WHERE "MYTABLE"."ID" = 10121  [["description", "some text"]]
```

and worse, if this results in an error the sql is only partial, the parameter part is lost..

Is there a way to get the logging the following way, so that I can execute the sql in eg Sql*Plus or SqlDeveloper ?

```
UPDATE "MYTABLE" SET "DESCRIPTION" = "some text" WHERE "MYTABLE"."ID" = 10121
```

I also wonder which SQL is effectively executed, in Sql*Plus or SqlDeveloper the logged syntax doesn't work.

Don't know if this is in Oracle/oracle_enhanced adapter alone or this is also the case with other adapters.

Comment: Yes, this syntax is almost certainly from the adapter you're using.  I'd check that project for log help